# jQuery DataTables - File becomes empty after dynamic change of filename

Tags: csv, datatables, tabletools

I want to dynamically change my exported CSV file name.

```js
accountsDataTable = $('#accounts-list').DataTable({
    "dom": 'Tlfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
        "aButtons": [{
            "sExtends": "csv",
            "sTitle": "Temporaire",
            "sButtonText": "Exporter en CSV",
            "mColumns": "visible",
            "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
                oFlash.setFileName("MonNomDeFichier.csv");
            }
        }]
    },
}
```

This does change the file name but the content is missing. I think `fnClick` function is missing `this.fnSetText` but I don't know what to put in it ?!

Comment: It works right away here. The default filename is set as `MonNomDeFichier.csv` - are you sure the SWF is loaded properly?

Comment: This does indeed change the file name, but it doesn't print out the content. The file is empty.

Comment: @Mehdiway , check my answer to see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
              oFlash.setFileName("MonNomDeFichier.csv");
              this.fnSetText( oFlash, this.fnGetTableData(oConfig) );//Add this after your code, since you have overridden the original code 
           }
```

Check here for more info :
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10248/fnclick-callback-on-tabletools-flash-button-breaks-csv-xls-export